Show that a function including a linear combination and a quadratic form is convex on the simplex
I have the following function
$$S(\boldsymbol{w}) = \sum_{i = 1}^K w_i E|X_i - \mu| - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i = 1}^K \sum_{j = 1}^K w_i w_j E|X_i - X_j'|$$
where the $w$s are on the simplex $\boldsymbol{w} \in \Omega = \{ w_1, ..., w_K : \sum_i w_i = 1, w_i > 0\}$. $X_i$ is the random variable of a continuous distribution, $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent but could have the same distribution, $X_i$ and $X_i'$ are independent copies of the same random variable, and $\mu$ is some constant in $\mathbb{R}$. I think, however, it's okay to treat all the expectations as constants.
I want to show that $S(\cdot)$ is convex in $\Omega$.  Of course $\sum_{i = 1}^K w_i E|X_i - \mu|$ is convex, but it's more difficult to show for the second term.  My thought is to take the matrix $Q$ where $Q_{ij} = -(1/2)E|X_i - X_j'|$ and say that it is positive semidefinite which would be enough to say the second term is also convex. But I don't think that's correct to assume that $Q$ is positive semidefinite. Is there a nicer way to prove convexity?

The $Q$ you have can even be negative semidefinite. To see this suppose all $X_i, X'_i \sim N(0, 1)$, the standard gaussian distribution. Then $Q = -\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}^{\mathsf{T}}$.

@VHarisop Your $Q$ is negative in general, but on the subspace $\ker 1^T$ is it zero, hence convex.
